# Changing .NetCore App launchSettings.json for deployment on Azure

Tags: json, azure, asp.net-core, iis, deployment

This is my first ever application deployment and I am running into issues with debugging. I tried logging into my app on azure and received this error.

[image]

So I thought it might be my launchSettings.json which is still pointing to development as of the time I deployed the app.

However, I don't know what to change my launchSettings.json to.

This is how it looks

```
{
 "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63990",
  "sslPort": 44376
 }
},
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"ManagementApp": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I need to change this to match something so I can switch from **Development mode** but don't know which setting from Azure goes where

Comment: launchSettings.json only applies when you run the project locally. It does not apply in Azure. You have an exception in your app, and you'll need to track that down.

Comment: @juunas Thanks...I was saying that because my app runs perfectly locally...Its only when I deployed that I see this error

Comment: Yeah, something is going wrong :) you should get some logs from the app to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Yikes! Will try to figure out then....Thanks @juunas

Comment: How did you publish to Azure? You should set production mode via environment variable of the application pool or in the final web.config file.

Comment: @LexLi Since its a .NetCore, it has no web.config.....I agree I need to set production mode but got no clue how to do that

Comment: Nope. There is always a web.config for .NET Core apps, or IIS won't know where is ASP.NET Core module or where is your web app. Based on your words, I can only assume that you publish your code directly to Azure, and let Kudu build it for you. That indeed hides the actual web.config from you. But you can always add a web.config to your project. In all, I suggest you consider other publishing options, as they allow you to call `dotnet publish` and then publish the artifacts to Azure, where you can see and modify the generated web.config.

Comment: @LexLi Yeah you are right. The app was built with Kudu so thats what made me think there is no web.config. But if so, can't I find web.Config locally and make the changes and republish it?  Its so weird to me that everything is fine locally but can't even get the error on Azure to debug it

Comment: Well, locally VS hides the complexity from you too, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 So the error only happens in the last step where no tool hides it from you any more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206879/discussion-between-mykel-and-lex-li).

Comment: @LexLi  continue this discussion in chat.