# WebAssembly launchSettings.json file in deployed/hosted asp.net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

How to deal with ./Client/Properties/launchSettings.json in deployed/hosted asp.net core  WebAssembly in Azure?
I read on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972370/changing-netcore-app-launchsettings-json-for-deployment-on-azure) that in deployment `launchSettings.json` does not get read.

Is it just a matter of converting all these settings to Environment Variables?

If it doesn't get read? Is there any point to having a 'Deployment' profile defined in here?

I am using GitHub actions to deploy. (generated automatically during the Azure App creation process)

**launchSettings.json contents**

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:29616",
      "sslPort": 44304
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ST_reports": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just a matter of converting all these settings to Environment Variables?

No, declaring all, at per environment, the application will choose appropriate configuration.

> If it doesn't get read? Is there any point to having a 'Deployment' profile defined in here?

It is your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify.

The launchsettings.json file DOES get read.
If you are deploying with dotnet via github action workflow for instance the `--configuration` or `-c` in your yml workflow will take care of that for you. (same goes for ./Client/wwwroot/appsettings.json file)

If you choose a github repo to build from during the Azure App creation process, a workflow like this one will be generated automatically.

```yaml
  
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134798
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135048

name: Azure App Service - STR(Production), Build and deploy DotnetCore app

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - live_branch

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    # checkout the repo
    - name: 'Checkout Github Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master


    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '5.0.x'

    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

    - name: Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ShowTexReports
        slot-name: Production
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_59C84BEF40F14C2CB32AF63670038D8F }}
        package: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

So don't do what I did and have .gitignore exlude that file for you.
Because your build will not function propperly.

My Webassembly app would be stuck `on Authorizing..` after partially rendering with the error message in console.

`blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100] Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL`